# How to center the parent while preserving children

Tags: android, html, css

Hey I am trying to put the spinner centered height vertically, so it's in the middle of any page.

```
<body>    
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
    <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The styles for `.spinner` are here:

```
.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
```

I tried changing height to `height:100vh;` but it messed up the inner divs. How do I move the center div to the center of the page and preserve the spinner I found here: http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

Comment: `position: absolute;` and center using that?

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
  position: relative;
}

.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%

  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
```

With the margin: -20px 0 0 -20px; you will reach the exact center. This is because, the top: 50% and left: 50px will display the element starting from the center.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intenion.

Comment: I have just updated the post with with an explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%
}
```

try to use absolute and top & left with 50%; it will put them in center